# How to create a local bitcoin network with 2 peers?

Tags: network

I want to create a locally bitcoin network. I use testnet and testnet-in-box, both of them working well. but they use the testnet-blockchain, I want to test the real blockchain. so I use two PC, one is win7, and the other is ubuntu in vBox.
In the bitcoin.conf of win7:

```
testnet=0
irc=0
dnsseed=0
upnp=0
listen=0
checkpoints=0
connect=192.168.1.126:19000
gen=1
rpcuser=test
rpcpassword=123
port=19010
rpcport=19011
keypool=5
```

and in the bitcoin.conf in ubuntu:

```
 testnet=0
     irc=0
     dnsseed=0
     upnp=0
     listen=1
     checkpoints=0
     connect=192.168.1.124:19010
     rpcuser=test
     rpcpassword=123
     port=19000
     rpcport=19001
     keypool=5
```

In win7 : 
     the bitcoin-qt show "No active connections to bitcoin network"

In ubuntu:
     the bitcoin-qt show "8 active connections to bitcoin network"

I think the status in ubuntu is not correct, because I want it only connect to the bitcoin-qt in win7. 
and I also want to know how to mine in this local network?

OK... I found the bitcoin-qt under ubuntu doesn't configured by `bitcoin.conf`. So I use 
`bitcoind -datadir=~/.bitcoin -daemon` to run the service. and this time, I got "1 active connections to bitcoin network". and I am sure they link to each other.

Comment: In the future, please rather put the answer in an answer post instead of adding it to the question.